# D3.js: Get parentNode after append

Tags: dom, d3.js, append, structure

I would like to append elements in a loop to a "root"-div and then go back up the DOM-tree to append another element / set the text (in D3.js).

The desired structure:

```
root > div > div 
           > text
     > div > div
           > text
     > ...
```

The code:

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js">
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    d3.select("#root")
      .append("div")
        .append("div")
        .parentNode
      .text("text");
  }
  
</script>
```

The error-message:

```
[...].parentNode is undefined
```

Is there a way in D3 to go up the tree after appending an element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume your code above is just for illustration because it could be written:

```
d3.select("#root")
    .append("div")
    .text("text")
    .append("div");
```

That said, you could use:

```
var div = d3.select("#root")
    .append("div")
    .append("div")
    .select(function(){
      return this.parentNode;
    })
   .text("text");
```

Problem with this is the `.text` is going to overwrite the child div.

So, to avoid that how about:

```
var div = d3.select("#root")
    .append("div")
    .append("div")
    .select(function(){
      return this.parentNode;
    })
   .insert("span","div")
   .text("text");
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/33Ka9ddXMBua1O1cL1W0?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks, that did it - with a small modification: I used append("span").text(...) instead to place the text behind the div.